# Add SSL Cert to an existing VM linux vm from Azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault

How you add SSL Cert to an existing azure Linux VM from Azure Key vault. for windows we use the following command

```
$vaultId=(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VaultName $keyVaultName).ResourceId
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore "My" -CertificateUrl $certURL
```

Is there a similar one like this for linux vm? Is there a link similar to this for linux [Secure IIS web server with SSL certificates on a Windows virtual machine in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Azure Cli to do this. Using following command.

```
secret=$(az keyvault secret list-versions \
          --vault-name $keyvault_name \
          --name mycert \
          --query "[?attributes.enabled].id" --output tsv)
vm_secret=$(az vm format-secret --secret "$secret")

az vm update -n shui -g shuikeyvault --set osProfile.secrets="$vm_secret"
```

Then the certificate stores on `/var/lib/waagent`, you could use Azure Custom Script to use it.

Note: You should use `"$vm_secret"`, I test in my lab, only `$vm_secret` does not work for me.

Comment: it is no longer `format-secret` but `secret format` https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/5946

Comment: How do you use Azure Custom Scripts to use it once the vm has access to the secret?

Answer (score 0):

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub aht@myserver. But if you have rights to the VM but not the original key, you want to use azure vm reset-access to do so. It is in fact documented as a standalone ability:
help:      -M, --ssh-key-file  path to public key PEM file or SSH Public key file for SSH authentication (valid only when os-type is "Linux")
of course, it doesn't say what ELSE should happen here in order to ADD the key I provide to the currently running VM I'm targeting. But the result needs to be that if I specify a user that already exists, and there's a key already there, this one needs to be added to the directory.

You'll note that in Azure/azure-linux-extensions#295, https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/issues/295 believes that using azure vm set-extensions ,then reset-access is broken.

Update a Key Vault for use with VMs
Set the deployment policy on an existing key vault with az keyvault update. The following updates the key vault named myKeyVault in the myResourceGroup resource group:

Azure CLI

Copy
az keyvault update -n myKeyVault -g myResourceGroup --set properties.enabledForDeployment=true

Comment: this is not exactly i was looking for. I have an apache linux web server and would like to update that ssl cert. I have already uploaded the SSL cert in Azure Key Vault. For window Add-AzureRmVMSecret imports the puts it in Certificate store. If I create a new linux vm through the template it copy the certificate to /var/lib/waagent/. for existing vm how do i do it?