# Is it possible to update already deployed VM to use Azure KeyVault?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, key-management

I have about 200+ VMs (Windows & Linux) already deployed in Azure. I want to know if it is possible to use either Powershell or Azure CLI to update the VMs to use KeyVault as a password/key manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You could use `az vm update -n shui -g shuikeyvault --set` to configure it. You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478552/add-ssl-cert-to-an-existing-vm-linux-vm-from-azure-key-vault).

In fact, you could create a VM to use Key Vault, then use `az vm show` to get this parameters and use `az vm update --set`.